# Java JPanel Resizing to Dimension(10, 10)

Tags: java, jpanel

I am creating a game, and I have a JPanel inside my JFrame, and I want my panel to maintain a constant size ratio: 1.3x1 (as large as possible). I have a component listener on the frame, and when the frame is resized it resets the size of the panel using `setPreferredSize`, the problem is that every time I change the frame size, the panel gets resized to a `Dimension(10, 10)` - meaning that the frame is always tiny. The frame also has a `GridBagLayout` set because i want the panel in the middle. In addition - sometimes if you resize the frame quickly (draw the corner fast) the frame will appear at the right size for a split second, then go back to `10, 10`.

Resizing code in the component listener:

```
Game.frameSize.x = (int) Math.round((GameFrame.frameSize.y - 2) * 1.2);
Game.frameSize.y = GameFrame.frameSize.y - 2;
this.panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Game.frameSize.x, Game.frameSize.y));
```

* *Game is my jpanel and GameFrame is my JFrame, Game.frameSize and GameFrame.frameSize is only for resizing sprites on the screen*

Configuration of the JFrame and the JPanel

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frameSize.x, frameSize.y));
frame.setSize(new Dimension(frameSize.x, frameSize.y));
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
frame.setResizable(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setFocusable(true);
Game game = new Game(frame);
Game.frameSize = new Vector((int) Math.round((GameFrame.frameSize.x - 2) * 1.3), GameFrame.frameSize.y - 2);
game.setSize(new Dimension(frameSize.x, frameSize.y));
game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frameSize.x, frameSize.y));
frame.addMouseMotionListener(new GameMouseMotionListener());
frame.addComponentListener(new GameComponentListener(frame, game));
frame.addMouseListener(new GameMouseListener());
frame.addKeyListener(new GameKeyListener());
frame.add(game);
```

I am really not sure what to do here, as far as google is concerned, no one has ever had this issue. Thank you, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Show us a bit more of your code. How and when is frameSize (i guess it's java.awt.Dimension) set?

Comment: Sorry for editing late, frameSize is a class that i made which only contains an x and a y (width and height)